# Adding appropriate debugger to BeagleBone Qt Kit

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, ubuntu, beagleboneblack

I downloaded gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.04_linux.tar.xz, extracted it and in Qt Kit selected debugger as arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb, and I get following error:

[image]

I am not sure why debugger is not appropriate for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a problem after several hours of searching for solution.

Follow these steps:

> sudo apt-get install gdb-multiarch

In your BBB kit for debugger select **gdb-multiarch** from **/usr/bin/**, it should work now!